# Is it possible to use thread factory in new fixed thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to use thread Factory in a fixed thread pool(eg - 10). How should I do it, I am not gettings any idea how to do that. I have used some naive approaches { which I don't think good to share :) }.

#### I have implemented earlier this with a SingleThreadExecutor by just passing the factory instance to its constructor but that's not the case with the fixed thread pool.

For SingleThreadExecutor I have used this earlier.

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new SomeThreadFactory());
```

I'm focused on -> java.util.concurrent package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a fixed size thread pool, the `size` is necessary, `thread factory` is optional, for example:

```
int size = 1;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size, new SomeThreadFactory());
```